$\ell$- vs. $p$-adic and de Rham vs. Betti in the geometric Langlands correspondence
In Emerton–Gee–Hellmann’s IHÉS notes on the categorical $p$-adic local Langlands programme, one finds the following remark:

The differences between the $\ell$-adic and $p$-adic settings are reminiscent of the differences between the Betti and de Rham versions of geometric Langlands, although for reasons of ignorance we are unsure of how seriously one should take this analogy.

Recently, the Betti geometric Langlands correspondence has been showed to be equivalent to the de Rham one, by the Riemann–Hilbert correspondence and the equivalence between the restricted and the full correspondence. On the other hand, I know little about the successive development of Emerton–Gee–Hellmann‘s work, but I hope the following questions do make some sense:

How much has this analogy been understood? What about the situation after lifting to the derived category of $p$-adic sheaves on $\operatorname{Bun}_G$?

How do the geometrized Langlands conjectures take into account of Arinkin–Gaitsgory–Kazhdan–Raskin–Rozenblyum–Varshavsky’s program which applies in any sheaf-theoretic context?

For the other direction, should we furthermore expect analogies of the geometrized real local (developed by Scholze recently) and even the global Langlands correspondence (from the $\mathcal{D}_{\mathrm{lis}}(\operatorname{Bun}_G, \overline{\mathbf{Q}_\ell})$ point of view, the global analogy of Fargues–Fontaine curve does not exist, but Scholze made a opposite comment here) in the “classical” geometric Langlands program?


I believe that a comprehensive answer to these questions is completely unclear at present, so comments on basic principles or simple examples to think about are welcome.

You can right-click on the timestamp of a comment to get a link to that specific comment.  The link as it stands will come with some cruft; for example, for Peter's comment, it's https://mathoverflow.net/questions/473738/geometrization-of-the-global-langlands-correspondence#comment1230996_473738. This can be used directly (although there are some issues where it might not work on, if I recall correctly, questions that span multiple pages), or it can be trimmed down robustly to https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1230996.  I edited accordingly.

Here, as promised, is a second answer. Let me warn you that I am much less confident about this, and possibly everything below is completely wrong.
The TL;DR is that there is some qualitative analogy between the Fargues-Scholze story with $p$-adic coefficients, and de Rham geometric Langlands. HOWEVER, there is still not a precise categorical conjecture with $p$-adic coefficients!
Nevertheless, I think it is reasonable to expect that such a conjecture exists. Let me speculate about what form it should take. In what follows I will freely use some notation from Emerton-Gee-Hellmann's amazing IHES notes. If you haven't read these notes, this answer won't mean much anyway.
For simplicity I will fix a finite extension $F/\mathbf{Q}_p$ and consider the group $G=\mathrm{GL}_n/F$. Then $\mathrm{Bun}_G$ is the same as in my previous answer.
On the spectral side, we have the Emerton-Gee stack $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{X}_{n,F}$ of rank $n$ etale $(\phi,\Gamma_F)$-modules. This is a Noetherian formal algebraic stack, locally formally of finite type and flat over $\mathbf{Z}_p$, which (appropriately interpreted) is a local complete intersection of pure relative dimension $[F:\mathbf{Q}_p]n^2$. It also has an underlying reduced substack $\mathcal{X}_{\mathrm{red}}$, which is equidimensional of dimension $[F:\mathbf{Q}_p]n(n-1)/2$.
This is VERY FAR from being an affine quotient stack as in the $\ell$-adic case. When $n=2$ and $F=\mathbf{Q}_p$, for instance, it has a coarse moduli space which is a chain of $\mathbf{P}^1$'s. For $n>2$ or $F \neq \mathbf{Q}_p$, its coarse moduli space is essentially trivial! This makes it hard to write down perfect complexes on $\mathcal{X}$. In fact, it seems to be an open question whether $\mathrm{QCoh}(\mathcal{X})$ is compactly generated.
I hope that the following is true in some form:

There should be a sheaf category $\mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Bun}_G)$ equipped with a tensor action of $\mathrm{QCoh}(\mathcal{X})$. The sheaf theory $\mathrm{Shv}$ should have the property that for any finite type $\mathbf{Z}_p$-scheme $S$ on which $p$ is nilpotent, maps $S \to \mathcal{X}$ can be identified with symmetric monoidal functors $\mathrm{Rep}(\hat{G}) \to \mathrm{QCoh}(S) \otimes \mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Div}^1)$ (satisfying some small additional condition). Passing to limits, we can apply this to the identity map $\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}$: this gives, for any $V \in \mathrm{Rep}(\hat{G})$, a universal object $\mathcal{E}_V \in \mathrm{QCoh}(\mathcal{X}) \otimes \mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Div}^1)$. The spectral action should be normalized by the expectation that $\mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Bun}_G \times \mathrm{Div}^1) \cong \mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Bun}_G) \otimes \mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Div}^1)$ ("categorical Kunneth"), and under this isomorphism the functor induced by the action of $\mathcal{E}_V$ should coincide with the Hecke operator $T_V:\mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Bun}_G) \to \mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Bun}_G \times \mathrm{Div}^1)$ constructed by an appropriate form of geometric Satake.

There should be a canonical equivalence of categories
$\mathbf{L}:\mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Bun}_G) \simeq \mathrm{IndCoh}(\mathcal{X})$ compatible with this action.

The category $\mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Bun}_G)$ should be compactly generated (since IndCoh is), and there should be a canonical ("miraculous") self-duality $\mathbf{D}$ on its compact objects. The functor $\mathbf{L}$ should intertwine this duality with Grothendieck-Serre duality twisted by the Chevalley involution.

The functor $i_{1!}$ embeds $D^b_{\mathrm{f.p.}}(\mathrm{Sm}.G)$ fully faithfully into $\mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Bun}_G)$, and the composed functor $\mathbf{L} \circ i_{1!}$ should be the functor EGH denote $\mathfrak{A}$.

Let $\mathcal{X}^{\mathrm{restr}} \subset \mathcal{X}$ be the maximal substack over which the universal $(\phi,\Gamma_F)$-module can be realized as a Galois representation. Let $\mathcal{O}^{\mathrm{restr}} \subset \mathrm{QCoh}(\mathcal{X})$ be its structure sheaf, viewed as an idempotent coalgebra object. Then the full subcategory $\mathrm{Shv^{restr}}(\mathrm{Bun}_G) \subset \mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Bun}_G)$ of objects such that $\mathcal{O}^{\mathrm{restr}} \ast A \cong A$ should admit a spectral decomposition over the coarse moduli space of $\mathcal{X}^{\mathrm{restr}}$, which is actually the moduli space of $n$-dimensional pseudorepresentations of $\mathrm{Gal}_F$.

The subcategory $\mathrm{Shv^{restr}}(\mathrm{Bun}_G)$ should be stable under Hecke operators, and on this subcategory the action of a Hecke operator $T_V$ should factor over an inclusion $\mathrm{Shv^{restr}}(\mathrm{Bun}_G)^{B \mathrm{Gal}_F} \subset \mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Bun}_G \times \mathrm{Div}^1)$. This is "because" after localizing onto the restricted substack, $\mathcal{E}_V$ is pulled back from a $\mathrm{Gal}_F$-equivariant vector bundle on $\mathcal{X}^{\mathrm{restr}}$.

The subcategory $\mathrm{Shv^{restr}}(\mathrm{Bun}_G)$ should be closely related to the category of ULA sheaves in $\mathrm{Shv}(\mathrm{Bun}_G)$ - at the very least, it should contain all ULA sheaves.

For $n=2$ and $F=\mathbf{Q}_p$, the functor $i_{1!}$ should be compatible with passing from full to restricted, "explaining" the results of this paper. However, in all other cases, it will not be compatible. The point is that when $n=2$ and $F=\mathbf{Q}_p$, $\mathcal{O}^{\mathrm{restr}}$ is actually a colimit of copies of the structure sheaf of $\mathcal{X}$, but this relies on the special fact that the coarse moduli space is very large in this case. (Note also that unlike in the $\ell$-adic case, the functor $i_{1!}$ CANNOT preserve ULAness in general: if it did, it would imply provably false finiteness properties for the cohomology of the Drinfeld tower.)

For a suitably "generic" Galois representation $\overline{\rho}: \mathrm{Gal}_F \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\overline {\mathbf{F}_p})$ with induced map $i_{\overline{\rho}}: \mathrm{pt}=\mathrm{Spec} \overline{\mathbf{F}_p} \to \mathcal{X}$, the sheaf $A_{\overline{\rho}}=\mathbf{L}^{-1}(i_{\overline{\rho}\ast}\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{pt}})$ should be a Hecke eigensheaf with eigenvalue $\overline{\rho}$. Its stalk at $b=1$ should be concentrated in degree zero, where it should be a finite direct sum of indecomposable admissible mod-$p$ representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$. Up to small details, these should be exactly the representations sought by Breuil and his collaborators. Any $\overline{\rho}$ such that $\mathrm{Hom}(\overline{\rho},\overline{\rho}(1))=0$ should count as "generic".

There should be a Whittaker sheaf $\mathscr{W}$ on $\mathrm{Bun}_G$ such that, to first approximation, $\mathbf{L}$ is inverse to acting spectrally on this sheaf. In particular, in the notation of 9., we should have $A_{\overline{\rho}} = i_{\overline{\rho}\ast}\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{pt}} \ast \mathscr{W}$ on the nose. However, unlike the $\ell$-adic case where the sheaf lives at $b=1$ and is easy to write down, this sheaf seems to live "somewhere else" on $\mathrm{Bun}_G$. For $\mathrm{GL}_n/\mathbf{Q}_p$, it seems to live at the point labelled by the bundle $\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}(1)\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathcal{O}(n-1)$ (or maybe at the generizations of this point).


Probably some of these things can be attacked for $\mathrm{GL}_2$, but this is ongoing work, and I've already said too many vague things here. Stay tuned.

Thank you so much for the answers! In the de Rham setting, problems come from the kernel of the map $\operatorname{Rep}(G^\vee){\mathrm{Ran}} \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{QCoh}(\operatorname{LS}{G^\vee}^{\mathrm{dR}})$, which leads to the vanishing conjectures etc., can one see a similar picture here?

Yes, I would expect a very similar picture around that part of the story!

I like how you conjecture the existence of a conjecture :-)

Well, formulating the right conjectures is really the hard part. :)

Let me leave two answers which hopefully address some of your questions. Today I will comment on the $\ell$-adic story. I need to think for a few days before trying to write something about the $p$-adic story.
The TL;DR of this answer is that there is a very strong analogy between the Fargues-Scholze picture with $\overline{\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}}$-coefficients, and Betti geometric Langlands.
Recall that in the Betti story, one would naively start with the category of all Betti sheaves on $\mathrm{Bun}_G$ (relative to a fixed projective curve $X/\mathbf{C}$). This category is too large, in the sense that Hecke operators give you sheaves on $\mathrm{Bun}_G \times X$ which are not "smooth in the $X$-direction." It was a wonderful discovery of Ben-Zvi--Nadler that this is rescued by imposing the condition of nilpotent singular support. This leads to the Betti geometric Langlands conjecture: the category $\mathrm{Shv_{Nilp}}(\mathrm{Bun}_G)$ of Betti sheaves on $\mathrm{Bun}_G$ with nilpotent singular support should be equivalent to $\mathrm{IndCoh_{Nilp}}(\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}})$. Here on the spectral side we have the stack of Betti local systems, which is a very nice object: it is a quotient of an affine (derived) scheme by some $\hat{G}$-action, and in particular it carries lots of tautological vector bundles associated with $\hat{G}$-representations. Then you can build the spectral action by declaring that these tautological bundles should act via the associated Hecke operators.
(Warning! The condition of nilpotent singular support on the spectral side is doing something very different than on the automorphic side. I would recommend that on your first pass, you ignore this extra string of symbols on the spectral side.)
Inside $\mathrm{Shv_{Nilp}}(\mathrm{Bun}_G)$, there is the smaller category $\mathrm{Shv_{Nilp,ind.constr.}}(\mathrm{Bun}_G)$ of ind-constructible sheaves with nilpotent singular support. This should be equivalent to the subcategory $\mathrm{IndCoh_{Nilp}}(\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}}^{\mathrm{restr}}) \subset \mathrm{IndCoh_{Nilp}}(\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}})$ of ind-coherent sheaves on the stack of Betti local systems with restricted variation. To get this stack, note that $\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}}$ has an affine coarse moduli space (it is just the GIT quotient of the presentation I mentioned above): then $\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}}^{\mathrm{restr}}$ is the disjoint union of the formal completions of $\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}}$ along the preimages of all closed points in the coarse moduli.
It might seem weird that $\mathrm{IndCoh_{Nilp}}(\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}}^{\mathrm{restr}})$ sits inside $\mathrm{IndCoh_{Nilp}}(\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}})$, but one cheap way to say how this inclusion looks is that $\mathrm{IndCoh_{Nilp}}(\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}}^{\mathrm{restr}}) \subset \mathrm{IndCoh_{Nilp}}(\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}})$ is literally the ind-completion of the inclusion
$\mathrm{Coh_{Nilp}}(\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}})_{\mathrm{fin}} \subset \mathrm{Coh_{Nilp}}(\mathrm{LocSys}_{\hat{G}})$ where "fin" on the left means that we are only looking at coherent sheaves which are set-theoretically supported on finitely many closed fibers of the map to the coarse moduli.
Both of these conjectured equivalences are now theorems; at the same reference one can also find a proof that they each imply the other.
Now, this entire story adapts basically verbatim to the Fargues-Scholze setting, with the important simplification that "on the automorphic side, nilpotent singular support is automatic". In other words, for $G$-bundles on the Fargues-Fontaine curve, Hecke operators are automatically giving you sheaves which are smooth in the curve direction! This is "because" the Fargues-Fontaine curve has very low genus so the global nilpotent cone is trivial, or (slightly less hallucinatory) "because" the mirror curve $\mathrm{Div}^1$ is (topologically) a single point.
There is also the nice simplifying feature that on the spectral side, nilpotent singular support is automatic as well. This leads to the conjecture that for quasisplit $G/\mathbf{Q}_p$ with a fixed choice of Whittaker datum, there should be an equivalence
$D_{\mathrm{lis}}(\mathrm{Bun}_G,\overline{\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}}) \overset{?}{\simeq} \mathrm{IndCoh}(\mathrm{Par}_G)$
normalized by compatibility with the spectral action on the Whittaker sheaf.
Here $\mathrm{Par}_G$ is the stack of $\ell$-adically continuous $L$-parameters $W_{\mathbf{Q}_p} \to \phantom{}^L G$ over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}}$ (the notation for this in Fargues-Scholze is $Z^1(W_{\mathbf{Q}_p},\hat{G})_{\overline{\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}}}/\hat{G}$). Qualitatively, it is extremely similar to the stack on the spectral side of Betti geometric Langlands: it is (almost) a quotient of an affine variety by a $\hat{G}$-action, so it has a nice coarse moduli which is (almost) an affine variety, there are lots of tautological vector bundles, etc. I say "almost" because it has infinitely many connected components, which does cause some headaches, but this is basically the only thing which goes wrong. On the other hand, it has no derived structure, so in some ways it's even nicer than the stack of Betti local systems.
This also has a version with restricted variation. On the spectral side, the category is EXACTLY analogous with the Betti story I wrote above. On the automorphic side, the right thing turns out to be the full subcategory $D_{\mathrm{lis}}(\mathrm{Bun}_G,\overline{\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}})_{\mathrm{ind.fin}} \subset D_{\mathrm{lis}}(\mathrm{Bun}_G,\overline{\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}})$ of ind-finite sheaves. Here a sheaf on $\mathrm{Bun}_G$ is finite if it is compact and ULA, or equivalently if the total length of its restrictions to all HN strata of $\mathrm{Bun}_G$ is finite. Recall that $\mathrm{Bun}_G$ has a HN stratification indexed by the Kottwitz set $B(G)$, and sheaves on the stratum labelled by $b$ are the same thing as (complexes of) smooth $G_b(\mathbf{Q}_p)$-representations. So finite sheaves are exactly the ones which can be built using finitely many shifts and cones from $!$-extensions of irreducible representations on strata.
It is not hard to see that the full conjecture in this setting implies the one with restricted variation. In some cases a strong converse is true, see Theorem 0.7 here.
One major complication in the de Rham story, which also seems to afflict the $p$-adic story, is that the stack appearing on the spectral side is far from affine, and it doesn't have many tautological vector bundles. This makes it a lot harder to construct the spectral action. But I will say more about this next time.

Let me add some assorted remarks I have heard while conversing with people in the community.
One thing that is sought after is to also understand how the theory of locally analytic representations fit into this story.
Regarding this, by recent work of Rodriguez-Camargo there is a stack $*/G^{\mathrm{la}}$ such that quasi-coherent sheaves on them encode (solid) locally analytic representations.
Going further, following the thread in the proposed in the geometrization of the real local Langlands correspondence, instead of just testing $\mathrm{Bun}_G$ on perfectoids, one should consider certain nil-perfectoids (bounded rings such that the quotient by the $\dagger$-nil radical is perfectoid, see also this paper). It would then be true that $*/G^{\mathrm{la}}\subset\mathrm{Bun}_G$ is an open immersion.
On the spectral side, one would have to find some solid enhancement of the Emerton–Gee stack, this is currently being worked on.
(Let me remark that this is ahistorical, and I am pretty sure the ideas in te geometrization of the real local Langlands correspondence are inspired by work on the $p$-adic program).
Let me also say, using the analytic de Rham stack one can try to make sense of $\mathrm{LocSys}_G=\mathrm{Maps}(X_{\mathrm{dR}},BG)$, where $X$ would be some family of Fargues–Fontaine curves. In fact this is much closer to the usual geometric Langlands program compared to the $\ell$-adic setting (where the analogy is a little bit more loose). For example this shows there is a map $\mathrm{LocSys}_G\to\mathrm{Bun}_G$ that is occasionally useful in the geometric Langlands program. However one should then figure out how this is related to the Emerton–Gee stack.
Finally, let me also make a remark regarding Hecke operators. As commented by Satan's Minion here, there are not so many easy to write down vector bundles on the Emerton–Gee stack, and certainly this question only becomes harder once one enhances this to some solid version thereof. I recently got convinced that there is a reason why compared to the $\ell$-adic program, there are more bundles to consider in the $p$-adic context, this will have to wait for another answer.
